# Adding NEW controller to a Ruby on Rails 4 Spree -Ecommerce application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, authentication, controller, spree

I am trying to add a new controller a Ruby on Rails 4 Spree -Ecommerce application. First of all, in `routes.rb` I added `root :to => 'login#login'` then in `app/controllers/` I added a file called `login_controller.rb` and in the file I added the following code.

```
module Spree
  class LoginController < Spree::StoreController
   def login
        render('spree/shared/_login')
    end
  end
end
```

When I start the server and go to localhost:3000/ I get this error

Unable to autoload constant LoginController, expected `superclass mismatch for class LoginController`

My goal here, is to require login to even view the home page of the store. I am attempting to build a site where users get a login screen when the go to it unless they are already logged in.

Please know that I am ruby noob and this is actually my first ruby on rails application so I am completely clueless here.

Also if there is a better way to go about doing what I want (requiring a login to basically view any page on the site) than my current apporach (having a LoginController which checks if there is a user logged in - if so redirect to home, if not redirect to Login) please let me know.

P.S. I got the layout for the controller from the home_controller.rb in the spree gem

Comment: Spree can integrate with Devise to generate all the Authentication within your application seamlessly. I suggest you watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pirTIAy1NVM), which walks through the basics of setting up an app and even teaches you how to customize it using [Deface::Override](https://github.com/spree/deface)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I did watch that video but it doesn't talk about authentication and I used Deface::Override to customize the front-end but I am stuck on customizing the backend. Can you point me in the right direction as to how do I go about integration Devise and ensuring that the user is logged in while view any but the login page?

Comment: I posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested the code, but I suggest you use Spree's [Devise integration](https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise)
then you can add a before filter mandating authentication. Create a [decorator](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/logic.html) to contain this logic addition. Create a file called base_controller_decorator.rb inside app/controllers/spree with the following code:

```
Spree::BaseController.class_eval do 
  before_filter :check_logged_in
  def check_logged_in
    unless spree_current_user 
      redirect_to spree_login_path
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: This worked just as expected! I just had to change current_user to spree_current_user.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you are in the `Spree` module you don't need the namespace for the superclass `class LoginController < Spree::StoreController` like so `class LoginController < StoreController`.